# Can't find my Python 3.3 syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "foo.py", line 6
    print "This implementation requires the numpy module."
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In this Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

try:
    import numpy
except:
    print "This implementation requires the numpy module."
    exit(0)

###############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    R = [
         [1,2,3],
         [4,5,6]
        ]
```

What is wrong?

**EDIT:** I use Python 3.3

Comment: please tell the python version

Comment: Using Python 3.x? [Print is a function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be:

```
print("....")
```

Starting with python 3, `print` is a function, not a special case statement.